# How to remove latch assembly that is stuck in edge bore?

Tags: doors, doorknob, knobs

I want to replace a door knob, but I have 2 problems:

1. After removing the door knob, I can't remove the latch assembly from the edge bore. Is there a mechanism to remove this from the door, or is it simply a matter of brute force?
2. The latch plate is different from the new one. Is it a matter of chiseling the side of the door to fit the plate, or do I need a completely different product?

[image: The latch assembly can't be removed from the door.]
This is an interior door for a residence.

Comment: Try grabbing the latch (yes it will try to slip out of the pliers) and rotating slightly back and forth, as well as pulling (there) and pushing (from inside.)

Comment: Chiseling to fit the plates is an option. I recall seeing knobsets that allow you to remove the rounded rectangle and swap in a round plate that could match your existing mortise. Step 3 in the sample instructions here -- https://www.schlage.com/content/dam/sch-us/documents/pdf/installation-manuals/P515-302.pdf -- shows the general idea.